# Getting SNS to work programmatically... works via command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Trying to make a simple call to SNS in my PROD environment but it keeps throwing a `SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN` error. This works great in my local and DEV environments with the same code.

I was initially passing in a cert to the AWS.config but took that out (see comments). Im guessing its looking for a cert somewhere but cant seem to find that in the AWS docs.

```
var AWS = require('/projects/aws-sdk/node_modules/aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs'), https=require('https');
//var certs=fs.readFileSync('/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/ca-bundle.pem).toString().split(/(?=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----)/);
AWS.config.update({
  httpOptions: {
    agent: new https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized:true})
    }
  });

AWS.config.update({
   region: 'us-iso-east-1'
  });

var params = {
   Message: "SNS Test",
   TopicArn: 'arn:aws-iso:sns:us-iso-east-1:7446189262331:SNS_EROR_PROD' };

var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion:'2010-03-31'}).publish(params).promise();
logger.info("publishPromise:"+JSON.stringify(publishTextPromise));
logger.info("Before call to promise");
publishTextPromise.then(
   function(data) {
      logger.info("inside call");
    }).catch(function(err) {
      logger.info("CATCH ERROR", err);
    });
```

Everything seems to work up until the `publishTextPromise.then` and it falls into the `catch` block throwing that cert error.

When I log out the value of `publishTextPromise` I get what I think is garbage: `publishPromise:{"_c":[],"_s":0,"_d":false,"_h":0,"_n":false}`

As a separate test I used the command line CLI to subscribe to that sns topic and publish a message to it. It works great in PROD! Command line works, but the code does not. Weird.

My example above I took straight out of the AWS docs so I would think it would work? Hopefully someone sees something dumb I might have missed!
thanks all!

Comment: The TopicArn looks weird to me.  What is the "iso" part?  I just created a topic in `us-east-1` and the ARN is `arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890:test-topic`.

Comment: When I create my topic via the SNS dashboard thats how it shows up for me. I just copied what it generated. I can also create an SQS and test it directly from there and the topic appears to work.